# Is product of any isometries in $\mathbb{R}^n$ an isometry?

Tags: linear-algebra, isometry

I am reading the book Putnam and Beyond by R.Gelca and T.Andreescu, and there is the following problem (#118):

> Let $V_1,V_2,...,V_m$ and $W_1,W_2,...,W_m$ be isometries of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($m,n$ positive integers). Assume that for all $x$ with $||x|| \leq 1$, $||V_i x - W_i x|| \leq 1,\ i = 1,2,...,m$. Prove that:
>   $$
> \Big|\Big| \big(\prod_{i=1}^m V_i\big)\ x - \big(\prod_{i=1}^m W_i\big)\ x \Big|\Big| \leq m
> $$
>   for all $x$ with $||x|| \leq 1$.

Why the following solution is wrong (I presume that it's wrong because authors used a more sophisticated one and mine is too obvious):

We know, that isometries form a group, so $V = V_2 \cdot ... \cdot V_m$, $W = W_2 \cdot ... \cdot W_m$ are isometries too. That's why for all $x$ such that $||x|| \leq 1$ we have $||Vx|| = ||x|| \leq 1$ and $||Wx|| = ||x|| \leq 1$. But this means that vectors $Vx$ and $Wx$ satisfy the property from the task and we have $||V_1(Vx) - W_1(Wx)|| \leq 1$, which is the desired result (and even stronger).

P.S. If my argument is valid, then what condition should be added to the task so it is not valid anymore?

Comment: Could it be that the isometries are not necessarily linear, i.e., $V_i(0)$ need not be $0$? -- Alos, if if they are linear isometries, you only get $\|\|\le 2$ (but that would be good enough for $m\ge 2$)

Comment: I suppose they could be non-linear, but how does it change anything? Why would we get $||...|| \leq 2$? Condition in the task says that $||V_i x - W_i x|| \leq 1$ for any $x$ s.t. $||x|| \leq 1$

Comment: If $m\ge 3$, let all $V_i$ be the identity, let all $W_i$ be the same rotation by a $\pi/m$. Then $\|V_ix-W_ix\|\le 1$ for all $\|x\|1$, but the porudtc of all $W_i$ is negative identity and so $\|\prod V_i x-\prod W_ix\|=\|2x\|$ can be up to $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only conclude 
$$\lVert V_1(Vx) - W_1(Wx) \rVert = \lVert V_1(Vx)  - V_1(Wx) +  V_1(Wx) - W_1(Wx) \rVert \le   \lVert V_1(Vx)  - V_1(Wx) \rVert + \lVert V_1(Wx) - W_1(Wx) \rVert = \lVert Vx  - Wx \rVert + \lVert V_1(Wx) - W_1(Wx) \rVert \le\lVert Vx  - Wx \rVert + 1.$$

This reduces a product of $m$ isometries to one of $m-1$.

Comment: I just realized that the above argument only works when $\lVert Wx \rVert \le 1$ for  $\lVert x \rVert \le 1$. This holds if the isometries are linear, but in that case gimusi has observed that $\lVert Vx - Wx \rVert \le 2$ for any two isometries $V,W$ and any $x$ with  $\lVert x \rVert \le 1$. Hagen von Eitzen has shown that $=2$ can occur for $m \ge 3$. So the relevant case seems to be that isometries are arbitrary members of the Euclidean group $E(n)$.

Comment: The argument presented in the question breaks down when considering $\lVert V_1(Vx) - W_1(Wx) \rVert$. In general we have $Vx \ne Wx$, and even if they are equal one has in general $\lVert Vx \rVert > 1$ (unless the isometries are linear).

Comment: If all $V_i =$ identity and all $W_i = T =$ translation by some $v$ with $\lVert v \rVert = 1$, then we see that $=m$ is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your observations but then we should conclude that

$$\|Vx-Wx\|\le \|Vx\|+\|Wx\|\le 2$$